# What file systems support taking snapshot backups from a live system?

Tags: filesystems, backup

What file systems allows me to take a full snapshot of a full live partition, while active, in a state where all files have the same state as when the backup/snapshot process start ?

I want to be able to make full backups of live database by copying the files, and the files are constantly being modified, and a simple copy `cp -rf` to all files always leave different files in inconsistent state.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/314480/in-linux-how-do-i-create-restore-an-image-snapshot-of-my-entire-drive

Comment: It is usually best to use database intrinsic mechanisms to backup a database as it knows its own consistency requirements. For example, even if I were to make a perfect, instantaneous snapshot of the backing files for a DBM, I could still wind up with inconsistent state because there was something the DBM had in core at that instant and the file system has no knowledge of what it has not been told.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

zfs ( problematic fuse support on Linux at best ) and btrfs ( still in heavy development ), or any filesystem you choose if you stack it on top of LVM.